# Desenvolvimento para celular com Adobe AIR

Tags: mobile, actionscript-3, adobe-flex, adobe-air

Estou tentando desenvolver um chat, com listview customizado para video, imagens e etc. mas está causando muito lag.

Trava de tudo quanto é jeito! Até mesmo o touch, quando se passa de uma tela para outra.

Alguém já teve algum problema com isso e que possa me ajudar? Todo aplicativo para Android criado com o Flex Mobile Project ou Flash tem esse tipo de problema?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta foi fechada pela comunidade porque com os dados fornecidos não é possível dar uma resposta clara e objetiva. Porém, você pode editar sua pergunta adicionando logs, mensagens de erro, o código do aplicativo e algo que torne possível alguém responder à pergunta. Fique também à vontade para criar novas perguntas ou mesmo responder, mas sugiro ler sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) na nossa [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Boa noite. Minha antiga pergunta foi editada por conta de alguém não ter entendido completamente. Então vamos la. Gostaria de saber o seguinte: Vale a pena desenvolver aplicativos para android utilizando o Flex Mobile Project? Pergunto isso, por que tenho tentando desenvolver um chat, com listview customizados para video, imagens etc. Mas o lag está muito longo. Até o touch. Trava de tudo quanto é jeito: Touch, quando passa de uma tela para outra etc. Alguém já teve algum problema com isso? Por experiência, alguém acha vantajoso desenvolver para android ou ios utilizando o Flex ou Flash?

Comment: Re-editei a pergunta para que ficasse mais objetiva e que talvez permita sua reabertura.

Comment: *"vale a pena"* ainda mostra o quanto a pergunta é subjetiva. Deve permanecer suspensa.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, obrigado pela resposta de vocês. Mas é simples, basta alguém com experiência dizer se vale a pena ou não desenvolver para dispositivos móveis, utilizando a tecnologia ADOBE FLEX ou FLASH. Ficou claro agora?

Comment: Editei e reabri a pergunta, mas ainda recomendo fortemente seguir a orientação do @utluiz mais acima: se a resposta for que o Flex/AIR em si não é a causa do problema, fica impossível te ajudar sem ver seu código.

Comment: Fico feliz com a ajuda dos moderadores! A comunidade AS3, enfim, está crescendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Adobe AIR, por trabalhar em cima de uma VM, deixa a performance a desejar em relação à linguagem nativa do aparelho (seja JAVA ou Obj-C). Isso se compromete ainda mais quando se utiliza muitos objetos no palco de exibição ou uma linha de código "longa demais".

*"Eu trabalho com Flash e Adobe AIR e sei o quanto isso incomoda, até mesmo em Desktop."*

Algumas dicas que tomei como recurso de diminuir esses travamentos:

- Evitar de utilizar "alpha = 0" e sempre que possível, utilizar "visible = false". Com o alpha, embora o objeto não seja visto, ele continua no palco e sendo renderizado. Com o visible isso não ocorre;
- "Copiar" os objetos e não "Duplicar". Sempre que possível utilizar/adicionar o mesmo objeto na tela;
- Cuidado ao utilizar filtros e efeitos nos MovieClips e TextFields, como sombras, beziel, etc... Isso em conjunto com uma interpolação exige muito do processador;
- Há uma dica que ajuda bastante: renderizar os objetos no palco como Bitmap: *Propriedades* -> *Exibição* -> *Renderizar* -> *Exportar como bitmap*;

Fora isso recomendo testar em outros dispositivos e verificar a performance. Muitos dos aplicativos que criei foram simples, mas sem estes problemas com "lag", creio que essas dicas irão ajudar bastante.

Infelizmente, aplicativos Adobe AIR enfrentam este problema, que "não há cura, apenas tratamento".

Comment: Pessoal, boa tarde. Gostaria de saber se vocês poderiam indicar sites como o androidhive.info que compartilha informações sobre desenvolvimento nativo de aplicações mobile, só que neste caso, eu gostaria que fosse para o Flash Mobile. Como práticas para o desenvolvimento etc. Não tenho a intenção de criar aplicativos grandes, mas aplicativos bons e que sejam multiplataforma. Neste caso também, gostaria de criar aplicativos que não tenham muito travamentos, isso é chato e faz com que o usuário nunca mais volte. ;)